Web Audio API - "EncodingError: Decoding failed" on IOS only when decoding mp3 chunks
I'm streaming mp3 chunks that are generated by a 3rd party to the browser via socket io.
The audio format is mp3 with 44.1kHz sample rate at 192kbps.
I'm using standardized-audio-context (https://github.com/chrisguttandin/standardized-audio-context) for extensive compatibility.
I'm starting to play the first chunk as soon as it arrives - it's a bit bigger than the rest and it's a valid mp3 that can be decoded on it's own. Subsequent chunks aren't valid mp3 files that can be decoded by decodeAudioData() in the browser, i.e. they don't begin and end exactly at the internal chunk boundaries of mp3.
Arbitrarily concatenating on the server the chunks that are generated by the 3rd party without paying attention to mp3's internal chunk boundaries, and as a result streaming bigger chunks (e.g. groups of 50 small chunks), seems to be working when playing the audio on Windows, but not on IOS. I imagine the internal implementation of decodeAudioData() is different.
How would you go about turning the received mp3 chunks into valid ones that can be decoded on IOS? Or how would you otherwise approach this? The goal is to stream to the browser in real time audio that's generated by AI.
The following StackOverflow thread is not mine, but I believe the answer there touches the issue:
WebAudioAPI decodeAudioData() giving null error on iOS 14 Safari

Yeah, basically by arbitrarily chopping the stream, you're creating an invalid MP3 stream and the different decoders have different levels of tolerance for this.  It's particularly the case that decodeAudioData() expects correct data where using a normal media element like <audio> can be more tolerant.
In any case, skip this entire approach and use regular HTTP.  By going the Web Socket route, you're just adding overhead and dependencies when it isn't needed.  If you just use HTTP(S), you can do something like this:
<audio src="https://example.com/your-stream"></audio>

Or...
const audio = new Audio('https://example.com/your-stream');
audio.play();

The browser will handle all the buffering logic and everything for you, and you can go about building your application.
